# Texture "compression" issue

Tags: modeling, texturing, image, uv-image-editor, compression

I am doing a model for my low-poly game and i have encountered a issue with the texture that i can't find anywhere how to fix it. Basically my texture becomes "compressed" and it's quality drops ALOT when i save the image in the model. The first one is the compressed version, while the second is what i wanted it to look like

[image: It isn't supposed to look like this]
[image: Actually wanted to look like this]

Comment: In the Image Texture node, try Closest instead of Linear but it won't fix everything, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Ohhh.....that's it, i always forget the closest option. Ty so much!

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

In the *Image Texture* node switch from *Linear* to *Closest*.